# Vector.push_back(...) read access violation

Tags: c++, vector

I don't know why but my program triggers a breakpoint on a line on the first iterations of 2 embedded loops here is the line:

```
pointerHolder->linkedVertices.push_back(&sphereApproximation.vertices.back());
```

Here is the section within which this resides (the line is near the bottom):

```
static const vertice holder[6] = { vertice(0,r,0,0), vertice(r,0,0,0), vertice(0,0,r,0), vertice(0,-r,0,0), vertice(-r,0,0,0), vertice(0,0,-r,0) };
std::vector<vertice> vertices (holder, holder + (sizeof(holder) / sizeof(vertice)));
shape sphereApproximation = shape(0, vertices);
int count;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    count = i;
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        if (count == 5) {
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            count++;
        }
        if (t != 2) {
            sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices.push_back(&sphereApproximation.vertices[count]);
        }
    }
}

bool * newConnection = new bool[pow(sphereApproximation.vertices.size(), 2) - sphereApproximation.vertices.size()]();
vertice * pointerHolder;
for (int i = 0; i < sphereApproximation.vertices.size(); i++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices.size(); t++) {
        if (!newConnection[(i * (sphereApproximation.vertices.size() - 1)) + t]) {

            pointerHolder = sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices[t];
            sphereApproximation.vertices.push_back(newVertice(&sphereApproximation.vertices[i], pointerHolder, accuracyIterator + 1));

            for (int q = 0; q < pointerHolder->linkedVertices.size(); q++) {
                if (pointerHolder->linkedVertices[q] == &sphereApproximation.vertices[i]) {
                    pointerHolder->linkedVertices.erase(pointerHolder->linkedVertices.begin() + q);
                    break;
                }
            }

            sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices.erase(sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices.begin() + t);

            sphereApproximation.vertices[i].linkedVertices.push_back(&sphereApproximation.vertices.back());

            std::cout << "gets here" << std::endl;
            pointerHolder->linkedVertices.push_back(&sphereApproximation.vertices.back());
            std::cout << "does not get here" << std::endl;

            sphereApproximation.vertices.back().linkedVertices.push_back(&sphereApproximation.vertices[i]);
            sphereApproximation.vertices.back().linkedVertices.push_back(pointerHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the declaration for the `newVertice(...)` subroutine is missing, but I thought it was rather unnecessary, all that needs to be known is that its return type is `vertice` and it does return a `vertice` as I have tested. Here are the declerations of the structs I'm using:

```
struct vertice {
    int accuracy;
    double x, y, z;
    std::vector<vertice*> linkedVertices;
    vertice(double x, double y, double z, std::vector<vertice*> linkedVertices) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
        this->linkedVertices = linkedVertices;
    }
    vertice(double x, double y, double z, int accuracy) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
        this->accuracy = accuracy;
    }
};

struct shape {
    double center;
    std::vector<vertice> vertices;
    shape(double center, std::vector<vertice> vertices) {
        this->center = center;
        this->vertices = vertices;
    }
};
```

If I've failed to provide anything please drop a comment and I shall amend my question.

Comment: Do not store pointers to vector items.  If that vector is resized, those pointers become invalidated.  Second, don't hardcode values like `5` and `6`, assuming the vector has these many items.  Use `vector::size()` to ensure you have at least the proper number of items.  Last, don't erase items in the vector you're iterating over.  Forgot, an [mcve] please.

Comment: Two more -- why didn't you simply use `std::vector<bool>` instead of `bool *newconnection = new bool...`?  Also, `pow` is not guaranteed to give you the correct results when used with integer exponents like this `pow(sphereApproximation.vertices.size(), 2) `.  Just multiply the result by itself to ensure there is no chance of round-off error.

Comment: Basically, stop using raw pointers.  If you are actually sharing pointers between containers, then use `std::shared_ptr`.  Your current code has no coherence on which container actually owns what pointers.  If there is no coherence or not know what to do, then I suggest you use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<vertice>>` and let the last container that holds that pointer be the one that will automatically delete the memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I solved the problem due to your comments, thank you.